# Has this been deprecated in Ember.js?

Tags: ember.js

In Ember.js documentation it states that you can bind attributes to a Boolean value. However when I try to use either of the below and the value is false it does not apply the provided class names.

`<div {{bindAttr class="isEnabled:enabled:disabled"}}>
  Warning!
</div>`

`<div {{bindAttr class="isEnabled::disabled"}}>
  Warning!
</div>`

Is this functionality no longer available?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The functionality is still working, and is not deprecated.

If you can't make it work, I guess its because you guess `isEnabled` is a property of the view, but the view rendering context has changed, so you have to write:

```
<div {{bindAttr class="view.isEnabled:enabled:disabled">Warning!</div>
```

I suggest you to read the [View context changes gist](https://gist.github.com/2494968).

The code:

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.FooView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: "foo-template"
});​
```

The template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    The disabled view:
    {{view App.FooView isEnabled=false}}
    <br />
    The enabled view:
    {{view App.FooView isEnabled=true}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="foo-template">
    <span {{bindAttr class="view.isEnabled:enabled:disabled"}}>A div</span>
</script>​
```

And [the JSFiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/T58kw/).